# Interpreting HTML Tags in RDLC

Tags: rdlc

How can i interpret html tags like anchor tag and table in RDLC report. Is it really possible?

Or only text decorating styles tags are allowed in RDLC?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible in VS 2010. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786884/visual-studio-2010-rdlc-support-for-html), and the pertinent [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx).

Basically, in the data section, click first to highlight the cell, then right click and the menu will contain a section with "Placeholder Properties". Then under General, there's a field "Markup Type" which you can set it to "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles"

Answer (score 0):

VS 2005 and VS 2008 rdlc don't support any html formatting but I still found a way to format html tag in output as pdf file.

Instead of format, you can replace these special characters from output.

You can write an expression of any text box value which can be used as below:

```
=Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Fields!"your column name".Value,"&quot;",""""),"&amp;","&"),"&lt;","<"),"&gt;",">")
```

In above expression I have interpreted a few special characters, but you can add more or can keep less as per your requirement.