# Why doesn't my RDLC data display HTML content properly?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rdlc

Why doesn't my RDLC display the HTML content? I have saved encoded HTML formatted text in an `Nvarchar` field in the sql table like given below:

```
<p><strong>ANDSLASKNDKLSNALNDKLANDLANND</strong></p><pre><pre lang="c#">
```

Even in RDLC, I have checked the ***HTML- Interpret HTML tags as style*** option but still it doesn't display the formatted output.

Why?

Comment: Does the data contain html elements? If so it might be that the data (html elements) gets escaped before getting passed, causing it to print the actual characters instead of it being interpreted as html.

Comment: yes as I said that I have saved HTML encoded content in database nvarchar field.

Comment: @NickDeBeer check i have updated my question

Comment: Thanks for the update. What exactly is your output? As far as I know you can only render a subsets of HTML into reports (to protect it from html injection), so for instance you can use <B></B> instead of <strong></strong> and that bold the text. Have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3816594/1284637

Comment: my output consists of html tags, i just bolded the text

Comment: Yeah then its that only certain html elements are supported. If that fixed it, let me know and I will write an answer :)

Comment: i am just making them bold, italic, underline, paragraph and documentation says that it supports

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, only subsets of HTML can be rendered (to protect it from html injection). Instead of using `<strong>` you will have to use `<B>` to define bold text.

> When you import text that contains HTML markup, the data must always
>   be parsed by the text box first. Because only a subset of HTML tags is
>   supported, the HTML that is shown in the rendered report may differ
>   from your original HTML.
>   The following is a complete list of tags that
>   will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:
>
> - Hyperlinks: <A href>
> - Fonts: <FONT>
> - Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
> - Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
> - List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>

Taken from this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx

Comment: but nothing works, neither bold, nor italic, nor underline